# a small fortune vs. a large fortune

Tags: meaning

I am a student learning English.
I learned that 'a small fortune' means a large quantity of money.
Then, is a small fortune the same as a large fortune?
Is there no difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

A small fortune is a relative term. It depends on the circumstances of the people involved. To someone impoverished and reduced to begging, £50 might be considered a small fortune. However this is a trivial sum to a well-to-do middle class person to whom a small fortune might mean £100,000. Whatever the sum, it usually implies a life changing amount.
On the other hand, a large fortune is a lot of money by almost **any** standard. The cost of a luxury yacht or a large country estate.
IMHO I disagree with M-W the sum doesn't have to be "surprising or unexpected". I don't consider any of the M-W examples meet this description  . For example if you live in a draughty old house it is neither surprising nor unexpected that the heating bills will be large.

Comment: People say things like 'a doner kebab costs a small fortune these days'.

Comment: There is a joke. How can you make a small fortune at F1 motor racing? - Start with a large fortune.

Answer (score 2):

In modern English, a small fortune is a set phrase which has a very specific meaning. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small%20fortune) defines it as

> a surprisingly or unexpectedly large amount of money

By contrast, a large fortune is not a set phrase- it means exactly what it says. A fortune is a large amount of money: a large fortune is even more than a fortune.